# Merge 2 data sets in long format based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames that I would like to merge. The difference between the data sets is the number of observations and the way they er collected. In `df1`observation were recorded on 2 different days. Each record has an index , id1  person  identification number and id2 refers the number of the day that recording was made (day had to be different ).There is also a Day variable that records the week day when the recording was made.

In `df2` observations were recorded just based on serial number and id1 person identification number. There is just one observation per person. Similarly here there is also a Day variable that records when the recordings started.

I would like to identify the observations from df2 that were recorded on the same day as in df1.

I tried to create an newindex (to group index and id1) to go to long and merge based on days.

Df1:- day denotes when the observations were made (eg. index 12; id1 -denotes just 1 person; id2 denotes the 2 days -Wednesday id2 1 and Sunday id2 2)

```
    index id1 id2  Day         obs1 obs2 obs3
     12    1   1   Wednesday    1    11   12
     12    1   2   Sunday       2     0    0
    123    1   1   Tuesday      1     0    1
    123    1   2   Saturday     3     0    3
    123    2   1   Monday       2     2    4
    123    2   2   Saturday     1     0    8
```

df2: -here the day Day variable denotes the starting day from which the observations were made (eg. id 12 day2 and id 123 day1)

```
index   id1  Day       day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6  day7   
 12      1    Tuesday     2    1    2    1    1    3    1    
123      1    Friday      0    3    0    3    3    0    3
```

Outcome:

```
 index id1 id2   obs1 obs2 obs3 
 12      1   1     1   11    12   
 12      1   2     2    0     0
 123     1   2     3    0     3        
 123     2   2     1    0     8
```

Sample data

df1:

```
structure(list(index = c(12, 12, 123, 123, 123, 123), id1 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2), id2 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), Day = structure(c(5L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday"), class = "factor"), obs1 = c(1, 2, 1, 
3, 2, 1), obs2 = c(11, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), obs3 = c(12, 0, 1, 3, 
4, 8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

df2:

```
structure(list(index = c(12, 123), id1 = c(1, 1), Day = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Friday", 
"Tuesday"), class = "factor"), day1 = c(2, 0), day2 = c(1, 3), 
    day3 = c(2, 0), day4 = c(1, 3), day5 = c(1, 3), day6 = c(3, 
    0), day7 = c(1, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: when you say starting from day61-da696 and day71-day796.  it is in 7 day sequence, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
weekday <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
```

If the datasets are `haven` `labelled` 'Day', we first convert to `factor` with `as_factor`

```
library(haven)
df1$Day <- as.character(as_factor(df1$Day))
df2$Day <- as.character(as_factor(df2$Day))
df1$Day <- match(df1$Day, weekday) 
dt2 <- melt(setDT(df2), measure = patterns('^day\\d+$'))[seq_len(.N) >=
    match(Day, weekday)[1L]][, .(Day = match(Day, weekday)[1]), index]
merge(setDT(df1), dt2, by = 'index')[Day.y < Day.x]
#   index id1 id2 Day.x obs1 obs2 obs3 Day.y
#1:    12   1   1     3    1   11   12     2
#2:    12   1   2     7    2    0    0     2
#3:   123   1   2     6    3    0    3     5
#4:   123   2   2     6    1    0    8     5
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, it is better to return a `list` column in `summarise` and then `unnest` (in case the lengths are not matching with the number of rows)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = day1:day7) %>%
     group_by(index) %>% 
     slice(match(Day, weekday)[1L]:n()) %>%
     summarise(Day = match(Day, weekday)[1]) %>%
     inner_join(df1 %>%
     mutate(Day = match(Day, weekday)), by = 'index') %>%
     filter(Day.y >= Day.x)
# A tibble: 4 x 8
#  index Day.x   id1   id2 Day.y  obs1  obs2  obs3
#  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    12     2     1     1     3     1    11    12
#2    12     2     1     2     7     2     0     0
#3   123     5     1     2     6     3     0     3
#4   123     5     2     2     6     1     0     8
```

Comment: @user11964604 hi, can. you please check my updated for tidyverse

Comment: @user11964604. looks like your are using a. different attribute (haven) than the one showed in the dput

Comment: @user11964604 i am. not getting the logic from the comments.  Can you please post as a new question

Comment: @user11964604 i meant could you post as a new topic/question as others have also answered based on the previouss question

Comment: @user11964604 you can create a named vector and do the match

Answer (score 1):

We can get the `df2` lin long format, `group_by` `index` keep the rows which occurred after observations were made and join it with `df1` based on `index` and `Day`.

```
library(dplyr)
weekday <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
             "Saturday", "Sunday")


df2 %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches('day\\d+')), as.numeric) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = matches('day\\d+')) %>%
  group_by(index) %>%
  filter(row_number() >= match(Day, weekday)[1L]) %>%
  summarise(Day = match(Day, weekday)[1]) %>%
  inner_join(df1 %>%mutate(Day = match(Day, weekday)), by = 'index') %>%
  filter(Day.y >= Day.x)


#  index Day.x   id1   id2 Day.y  obs1  obs2  obs3
#  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    12     2     1     1     3     1    11    12
#2    12     2     1     2     7     2     0     0
#3   123     5     1     2     6     3     0     3
#4   123     5     2     2     6     1     0     8
```

You can then use `select` to only keep columns which are required.